# Shopify. Collecting all variants but only displaying one of each same variant

Tags: product, shopify, variants

I'm attempting to develop a custom view for a product single view in Shopify.  I'm having difficulty finding resources on extending standard functionality.  Standard functionality only allows drop downs or radio buttons.

e.x.

**size|color|sex** can have multiple entries per product.

So if i have **L|Black|Male** and a **M|Black|Male** as product variants
Shopify displays each of these as a single option and not a list of individual options to select from.

I would like to have my product select look similar to this shops product page
http://www.petermanningnyc.com/products/tshirt

I just can't seem to wrap my head around outputting the data from Shopify in a way that I can duplicate a similar functionality.

How do i do this?

Answer (score 2):

This page on the Shopify wiki should be what you're looking for: http://wiki.shopify.com/Tutorial_on_editing_existing_theme_to_use_products_with_multiple_options

It describes how to add some javascript to your theme that displays product options as separate dropdowns. Enjoy!

Comment: link not working